# Launch mobile Safari from UIWebView *without* modifying app source?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I'm developing a small site that will only be viewed in-app inside a UIWebView, and one page has several links to an external website. I'd like these to open in mobile Safari, but all links inside the app load within the webview. Modifying the source of the app isn't an option since the site needs to be live before any changes could be submitted.

Is there a way to force a link inside a UIWebView to launch mobile Safari using HTML/5 or Javascript? Mimic `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`? Sneaky, hacky workarounds or brilliant alternate solutions?

(And, out of sheer curiosity... why not?)

Answer (score 1):

It would be bad design to let sites access the frameworks on the iPhone via simple HTML. This would open up all sorts of security holes. Its not web behavior you want to alter, so I think you may need to change the app source. I still don't understand why that isn't an option. Could you go into more depth?

Comment: That makes sense- I never fully considered security risks. Changing the app source isn't an option due to time constraints; the webview contains an iAd-esque site for a holiday promotion, and needs to be live before we could push a new release. (No control over final server, either.) Launching mobile Safari was the ideal solution since the external site has poor usability + no way back to the promo site. Most likely going to try an iframe with custom nav on top, as cringe-inducing as that is.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a custom URL handler. Your website could then determine if the "broswer" is the app and serve custom URLs for those links you'd like to maintain (aka open) in your app. Then, any standard HTTP/s URLs would open in Mobile Safari.

In other words, have your web server provide urls like myappurl:// for the links you'd like your app to handle, and http:// which would open Mobile Safari.